# Can I publish symbols to VSTS?

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I'm currently publishing some NuGets to my VSTS feed. Is there support for VSTS acting as a Symbol Server as well so I can publish my symbol packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to [use VSTS as a symbol server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/15/vsts-is-now-a-symbol-server/)

I've also written a [blog post](https://www.codit.eu/blog/2018/05/17/exposing-debug-symbols-using-vsts/) on how to setup a symbol-server using a VSTS build definition where the symbols are published on a file share.  It's actually more as a step-by-step guide on how to publish and expose them via IIS

Answer (score 5):

You can [publish your symbols to a file share](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/steps/build/index-sources-publish-symbols). There is not presently support for using VSTS itself as a symbol server.

Comment: @aoetalks - Be sure to vote on this User Voice item if you are interested in this feature:  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2564053-treat-tfs-as-an-enterprise-symbol-server

Comment: And how exactly did you do that? do you have a local server on premise and created the file share?, if so how do you secure your server so only the hosted pool could write to it, or you created a VM in azure? if so how did you added the agent to TS? How do you mange the security so the share is visible only to your team? I'm not being sarcastic, I really want to know, administration and cofiguration wise TS feels like huge step backwards

Comment: There was a update to the User Voice item, this summer a preview version of a VSTS Symbol service will be available.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Source Link](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink). It is becoming a new standard or at least recommended way.

> SourceLink is a language- and source-control agnostic system for providing first-class source debugging experiences for binaries. The goal of the project is to enable anyone building NuGet libraries to provide source debugging for their users with almost no effort. Microsoft libraries, such as .NET Core and Roslyn have enabled SourceLink. SourceLink is supported by Microsoft.

In a case of VSTS Git repository and `.Net Core` project

1. Add nuget reference of `Microsoft.SourceLink.Vsts.Git` to your project - the one which will be `dotnet pack` later (as of now in preview - make sure you tick "Include prereleases" in VS Nuget Manager)
2. Add `<AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>` into `PropertyGroup` where the `TargetFramework` element is.
3. Add `.NET Core` task with command `pack`

The nuget package will now contain PDB files so you clients can easily debug your library.